# Keras fit_generator arguments ; Layer model_5 expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on image captioning generator project. I defined function. However in the fit_generator part I am having unexpected input error. I hope someone can help me with that.

Best regards.

```
# train the model
model = define_model(vocab_size, max_length)
# train the model, run epochs manually and save after each epoch
epochs = 20
steps = len(train_descriptions)
for i in range(epochs):
    # create the data generator
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
    # fit for one epoch
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    # save model
    model.save('model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
```

```
ValueError: Layer model_5 expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```